# Connection setup for Teams webhook on airflow is giving General Error <class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'>

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, airflow

I need to send notification of failed DAG from airflow to Teams channel.
From Teams I have captured the incoming webhook link and when I add it in Airflow UI - Admin - Connection - New connection I am getting *General Error class 'sqlalchemy.exc.DataError'*

Connection settings are as below-
Conn Id: mycon
Conn Type: HTTP
Host: webhookuri
schema: http

Let me know if you know any resolution for this

Comment: are you getting any error while creating incoming webhook? could you please share more details if you are building this connector or just trying to configure it?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT
No, I got the webhook successfully.
Error appears when I use this URL to setup a connection in Airflow.
In airflow I opened Admin - Connection page and added below details for new connection: 
Connection Id: Myconnection,
Connection Type: Http,
Host: Webhook Url,
Schema: https and when I save this I am getting above error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the problem was the that the DB has **a restriction of 100 maximum characters** for the field `host`.

Have you try storing the connection in environment variables?

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html#storing-a-connection-in-environment-variables

It should be something like:

`export AIRFLOW_CONN_MSTEAMS_WEBHOOK_URL=<your_msteams_webhook_url>`